# Bixby: want to redirect to web browser url on button click

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want my capsule to redirect to the web browser URL on the click of a button. I am not getting anything to redirect.

Is redirection to the web browser URL from Bixby is possible?

Any help, please.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the app punch out functionality. I would recommending looking at the documentation [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/design-principles.ux-policies#app-punch-out-policies) for more information.

There are two ways to open an external URL from Bixby:

1. `attribution-link` ([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/layout.content.section.content.attribution-link))
2. `app-launch` ([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch))

In general, `attribution-link` is the best method of launching a web URL from within your Bixby capsule. I would highly recommend reading through the [app punch out policies](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/design-principles.ux-policies#app-punch-out-policies) for guidance on where to place `attribution-link` and/or `app-launch` in your capsule's flow.